# IF/AND statement with three conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get a result using an If/And statement. What I need to do is:

- If `A5` is greater than 1500
- and `B5` is greater than 35
- and `C5` is less than 1%
- then `"Target Met"`, else `""`

Seems like this should be simple, but I can't get it to return the result I want. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

try  this

`=IF(AND(A5>1500,B5>35,C5<0.01),"Target Met","")`